# Prove if A is a set finite and B is infinite then $|A|+|B|=|B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove if $A$ is a finite set and $B$ is infinite then $|A|+|B|=|B|$

**My work**

I was thinking in solve this exercise by contradiction.

Suppose $|A|+|B|\not = |B|$ then $|A|+|B|=|A|$

Here im a little stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why does it follow from $|A|+|B|\neq |B|$ that $|A|+|B|= |A|$?

Comment: Why does it follow that if $|A|+|B|\neq |B|$ then $|A|+|B| = |A|$. That seems like a jump

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First show that $|B|+1=|B|$, then use induction over the size of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  adding a single element to a countably infinite set yields a set of the same cardinality...

Consider $\mathbb N$.  Define $\phi:\mathbb N\cup \{x\}\to\mathbb N$ by $\phi (x)=1$ and $\phi (n)=n+1 \, \forall n\in\mathbb N$. $\phi$ is a bijection.

As Cantor said, "I see it;  but I can't believe it."

Comment: The question does not specify that $B$ is _countably_ infinite, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm right, but any infinite set has a countably infinite subset

Comment: x @Chris: ... assuming at least countable choice is available.

Comment: @HenningMakholm as Steinberg once said,  "I defer to authority. "

Comment: @HenningMakholm In order to prove the above you need $B$ to have a countable subset. If $f : B \cup \{ a \}  \to B$ is a bijection where $a \notin B$, then $\{ f^n(a) : n \in \omega \}$ is a countable infinite subset of $B$ (because nobody maps back to $a$ again).

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, but where do you get such an $f$ from? The usual approach for that is to _already_ know a countable subset of $B$ and shift it by one, Hilberts-hotel style.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, of course. What I wanted to say is that the statement is not provable in ZF alone. It is false when $B$ is an amorphous set.

Comment: @Jonathan: Ah, then we're in agreement.